# How to devide a cell into multiple columns in excel using Spreadsheet::WriteExcel?

Tags: excel, perl, spreadsheet

In the below example `entity_id` and `pos` are headers and others are values for them.

```
|   Entity_id   |      pos      |
|   16580       | code  | count |
|               | 056   |  2    |
|               | 101   |  4    |
|               | 082   |  10   |
```

How can I create the above format using `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel`?

Answer (score 0):

```
my $format = $workbook->add_format(
                                    border  => 6,
                                    valign  => 'vcenter',
                                    align   => 'center',
                                  );

$worksheet->merge_range('A2:A5', '16580', $format);
```